# browserify подключить telegram

Tags: node.js

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки я отправлял в телеграм сообщение.
Для этого я установил browserify и node-telegram-bot-api, но никак не пойму как в app.js вывести мне новый модуль бота. Например, если просто генерировать uuid(), то все ок, в консоль выводит.

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
const Uuid = uuid();
console.log(Uuid);
```

Но, когда я пытаюсь подключить node-telegram-bot-api выпадают разного рода ошибки, что я делаю:

**app.js**

```
const bot = require('../utils/telegram');
bot.sendMessage('111222333', `Hello!`);
```

**../utils/telegram**

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = 'TOKEN';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

module.exports = bot;
```

В итоге, я получаю ошибки:

```
bundle.js:55879 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:55879)
    at Object.296../lib/telegram (bundle.js:55888)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at Object.456.node-telegram-bot-api (bundle.js:102855)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at Object.455.../utils/telegram (bundle.js:102802)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at r (bundle.js:1)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?